# Why are properties from spring-boot-dependencies not available in child POM?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jersey, dependencies

I am following the Spring documentation [Using Spring Boot without the parent POM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html). In my parent POM, I am defining an import dependency on `spring-boot-dependencies` in the `dependenciesManagement` section. In my child POM I then define a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-jersey`, not specifying any version. When I look at the dependency:tree, I see that all the jersey dependencies use the version specified in `spring-boot-dependencies`. All is well.

Now, in my child POM, I need to add another jersey dependency. In the `spring-boot-dependencies` POM, I see that a property `jersey.version` is defined. However, when I use `${jersey.version}` in my child POM, the property is not defined.

Why is `${jersey.version}` not available in the child POM?

Parent POM snippet:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Child POM snippet:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>  <!-- error here -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

From `spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom`:

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: you don't need provide version if dep in spring-boot-dependencies  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management

Comment: @Georgy: I need to add an additional dependency that is not in the spring boot dependencies, and wanted to use the same version as related artifacts  in the spring boot dependencies.

Comment: ok I see, since dependency jersey-media-sse not in spring-boot-dependencies maven does not resolve version, it does for dependencies which in spring-boot-dependencies but not for others. I believe if you put spring-boot-dependencies as explicit parent - it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are inherited only from parent POMs. This is stated in the maven documentation (unfortunately I can't find the reference anymore).